# “Person with red clothes” or “red person”

Tags: meaning

I noticed that we don’t call a person in red clothes “red person,” but we call a face with a red cream “red face,” eyes with red-colored lens “red eyes” or lips applied with a red lipstick “red lips.” Why is there the difference?

Comment: Because a "red person" would have to be red everywhere. Obviously, that can only be possible if you're talking about someone with red-colored skin, or people who are in their heart, red. Most of these uses of the phrase "red person" are not positive.

Comment: *"eyes with red-colored lens"* - the part of the eyes that is colored is the [**iris**](https://www.verywellhealth.com/iris-of-the-eye-3421680), although we also say someone has red eyes if the whites of their eyes (technically, the [**sclera**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sclera)) is bloodshot.

Comment: In your language do you call a person wearing red clothes a "red person".  Do you say that a person with red lipstick had "red lips".  There have been a number of similar questions from Korean speakers.  I wonder if there is something about the adjectival construction in Korean that makes this confusing

Comment: @James K “Red lips” is natural, but “red person” is unnatural but understandable. I think it’s the same with English.

Comment: So why is there a difference in your language?  Why is "red person" unnatural?  (I suspect the answer you give would be the same as in English)

Comment: @James K I think it’s a matter of precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A person who is wearing red clothes is not actually colored red, but lips that have red lipstick on them are now actually colored red.  We would only say a person was a "red person" if they were completely painted red.  We don't say "a red X" if the X is merely *covered* with something else that is red.

Please be aware that "red person" or "red man" in American English can also be an offensive reference to an American Indian, so you should be extremely cautious about using the phrase.